# Is it also recommended to duplicate data in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

So I know that for scalability and security rules (I'm sure there's more reason and I'd also like to know why), data in Database should be duplicated due to the nature of non-SQL database like Firestore. **So my question is do I also do the same for storing in Storage?**

Comment: I don't know why someone would ever want to duplicate an object in Cloud Storage. The reason why you duplicate data in NoSQL databases is the enable more flexible querying.  Cloud Storage doesn't really have queries.  It just has objects with unique paths.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just want another dev's thoughts about this

Comment: Duplicating data and flattening structures is called denormalizing. There was a great blog written by Firebase which covers it pretty well and even though it's outdated, the concepts are sound. Check it out [denormalizing is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)